# Difference between %5B% and %5B0%?

Tags: php, jquery

jQuery .serialize() turns "[]" into %5B%5D

PHP http_build_query seems to turn the first "[]" into %5B0%5D, the second into %5B1%5D, etc. So it seems to be using some kind of counter.

**Why are there differences in these almost identical functions?**

Is it just my browser that makes them different? How can I make sure the http_build_query doesn't add the extra counter (or let jQuery know I need the extra counter).

Comment: Are you sure you weren't encoding `[1]` in the latter case?

Comment: `%5B` is the encoded version of `[`.  The '0' you have there is a literal zero and not part of the encoded data.  The `%5D` is the encoded version of `]`.  So it seems you may have unintentionally encoded `[0]` (and then `[1]`) instead of `[]`.

Comment: I might be. You cannot turn 'array_keys' off I guess in PHP. Not really sure how jQuery doesn't add them then though :(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`%5B0%5D` is the encoded version of `[0]`, `%5B1%5D` is the encoded version of `[1]`, etc.

```
%5B is [
%5D is ]
```

The number in between is a literal character, not part of any %HH encoding.