# post HTTP query via HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httprequest, httparty

i want to use mailerlite API to add subscribers to a list

here is what APIdoc says to generate request

```
$subscriber = array(
    'email' => 'foo@bar.com',
    'name' => 'foo',
    'fields' => array( 
       array( 'name' => 'country', 'value' => "usa" )
    )
);
$subscriber = $ML_Subscribers->setId( LIST_ID )->add( $subscriber );
```

and it generates a query string like this

```
email=foo%40bar.com&name=foo&fields%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=country&fields%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=usa
```

and sends it to mailerlite server
my question is how to generate string via ruby HTTParty gem or rails methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for generating exact same result as php code you should use this gem
https://rubygems.org/gems/php_http_build_query

example of use

```
puts PHP.http_build_query({"a"=>"b","c"=>"d","e"=>[{"hello"=>"world","bah"=>"black"},{"hello"=>"world","bah"=>"black"}]})

#a=b&c=d&e%5B0%5D%5Bbah%5D=black&e%5B0%5D%5Bhello%5D=world&e%5B1%5D%5Bbah%5D=black&e%5B1%5D%5Bhello%5D=world
```

Answer (score 2):

ActiveSupport monkey patches Object to add #to_query method, you can call it on your hash to get the query string:

```
subscriber = {
  'email' => 'foo@bar.com',
  'name' => 'foo',
  'fields' => {
    'name' => 'country', 
    'value' => "usa" 
  }
}

subscriber.to_query
"email=foo%40bar.com&fields%5Bname%5D=country&fields%5Bvalue%5D=usa&name=foo"
```

Comment: thanks but there a little difference between to_query and desired response that make it unusable
%5B0%5D%5Bname
%5D=
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065392/difference-between-5b-and-5b0
thank you btw

Answer (score 1):

You can use MailerLite Ruby gem for that https://github.com/jpalumickas/mailerlite-ruby

```
client = MailerLite::Client.new(api_key: 'my-secret-api-key')
client.create_subscriber(email: 'john@example.com', name: 'John Smith')
```